# How to tie oAuth2 tokens to an identity?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm currently working on a project for content partners network. I would like to provide `Login with YouTube` feature, as well as other stuff.

So I'm currently implementing oAuth2 authentication, and when that succeeds I get `access_token` and `refresh_token`, but no identification (could not know who do tokens belong to, just by having them).

Is there any kind of global YouTube/Google User ID within https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly scope (or any other scope) that I could get with my tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) call with "[mine](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine)" = true. That will give channel id and all the information about user(channel).

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2C+snippet%2C+brandingSettings%2C+contentDetails%2C+invideoPromotion%2C+statistics%2C+topicDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: I've done that initially, but I'm concerned about how many channels does `mine=true` output in `items`. Is it always just 1, or can it be more (without any other params, just mine=true). If user has multiple YT accounts linked together, do more channels appear, or do they get access tokens for each acc/channel separately?

Comment: it only outputs 1, whichever channel user picked to authorize, even when he has more than one. You can read this post for more detail. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids

Comment: Okay, yea I thought this would make sense when I thought about it last night. Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this API, but the `etag` should change if the content at that URL changes, and could change at any time even if the content has not changed.

Comment: Ok, so etag in API is the etag used in HTTP caching? If thats the case, than it does change over time.

Comment: Yes, it is intended to be used to validate cached data.

Comment: Any suggestion of what should I use to identify an account with? As 1 user can have multiple accounts, I need to link the `tokens` with something permanent...

Comment: No idea. I am quite new to web development and I have never used that API as I said.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles

> To request the currently logged-in user's profile, send a GET request to the following URL. Note: For this request, you must provide an authentication token, which enables YouTube to identify the user.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default
```

Comment: Aha, I used `gdata.youtube.com` in past, and I know about this very API. However this is v2 and its nasty old XML, I'm trying to find something like this for v3.

Comment: I know with v3, I could get `yt:user:id` equivalent, by taking [2:] characters from channel ID using `/v3/channels/list`, but I'm worried to do that, since I don't quite understand how does this API work in case of multiple channels. 1 YT Account can have multiple channels? If so, do multiple channels appear in `items` of `/channels/list&mine=true`? Maybe I'm getting this wrong...

Comment: Or does user get to select which YouTube channel to use during oAuth2 prompt, therefore in such case each YT channel under same user has its own set of `access_token`s?

Answer (score 0):

You kinda sorta might be able to do this with a cookie.

1) you present your page with a set-cookie that redirects to the oauth2 google page.

2) user auths with google sends a redirect to the browser going back to your page.

3) the browser is redirected to your redirect page with your cookie.

Not great, but I think it should work.